# Get the employee list logged in into the specific account

Tags: netsuite

I am looking for the solution by which I can list out the employees those are currently logged in into the specific account in NetSuite. I am not able to find out any NetSuite API which does this. So I just want to know if there is any API which I can use or if not then what could be the alternatives to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API available to check if a user is currently logged in. The only thing you can get from NetSuite is the TimeStamp of the logins if it is Successful or Failed but it will not tell you when the user logs out or still actively in the account. You may want to check it at Setup > Users/Roles > View Login Audit Trail.

Answer (score 0):

I think one reason NetSuite doesn't keep track of users currently logged in is that there's no requirement that you log out. You can close the browser window or lose connection and they don't know.

Comment: Yeah that I can understand. but I don't think it would be much difficult to keep the track of active sessions, in fact they do (after sometime a pop up comes which session your session expire).

Comment: I think that's client-side, not server-side. No proof, though.

Answer (score 0):

you can always create a login audit saved search and schedule it so you can have an overview of the login status.